# Isomorphic groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I know that there is a formal definition isomorphism but for the purpose of this homework questions, I call two groups isomorphic if they have the same structure, that is  group table for one can be turned into the table for the other by a suitable renaming.

Now consider $\mathbf{Z}_2=\{0,1\}$ (group under addition modulo $2$) and $\mathbf{Z}_3^{\times}=\{1,2\}$ (group under multiplication modulo $3$). In general $\mathbf{Z}_n^{\times}=\{a|0\leq a\leq n-1 \text{ and }\gcd(a,n)=1\}$. Now the group table for $\mathbf{Z}_2$ is:
$$
\begin{array}{c|cc}
&0&1\\ \hline
0&0&1\\
1&1&0
\end{array}
$$
and the group table for $\mathbf{Z}_3^{\times}$ is:
$$
\begin{array}{c|cc}
&1&2\\ \hline
1&1&2\\
2&2&1
\end{array}
$$
Obviously these two groups are isomorphic because if in the first table, I replace $0$s by $1$s and $1$s by $2$s, I get exactly the second table.

However, if I write out the group table for $\mathbf{Z}_4$ and $\mathbf{Z}_5^{\times}$, there is no way that group table for one can be turned into the table for the other by a suitable renaming. This means that these two groups are not isomorphic but the question asks me to prove that they are isomorphic. Now what should I do?

Comment: There is no difference between the usual formal notion of "being isomorphic" and the one you propose to use!

Comment: In any case, you should look harder at the group tables for $\mathbb Z_4$ and $\mathbb Z_5^\times$!...

Comment: There is a suitable renaming. Keep trying...

Comment: In short, the two examples are all concerned with the structure of cyclic groups, et c'est la méme.

Answer (score 7):

You are incorrect in claiming that there is no way to turn one table into the other. But the key is that you are not just allowed to rename, you are also allowed to list the elements in a different order! (After all, listing the elements of $\mathbf{Z}_4$ in a different order in the table will not change the group or the operation, will it?) This amounts to shuffling rows and columns together: if you exchange rows 2 and 3, say, you should *also* exchange columns 2 and 3.

The table for $\mathbf{Z}_4$ is:
$$\begin{array}{c|cccc}
+&0&1&2&3\\
\hline
0&0&1&2&3\\
1&1&2&3&0\\
2&2&3&0&1\\
3&3&0&1&2
\end{array}$$
The table for $Z_5^{\times}$ is:
$$\begin{array}{c|cccc}
\times&1&2&3&4\\
\hline
1&1&2&3&4\\
2&2&4&1&3\\
3&3&1&4&2\\
4&4&3&2&1
\end{array}$$
If you are going to be able to rename the entries in the last table to match the first, then "1" must be renamed "0". Now, notice that there is only one of the remaining four elements that when operated with itself gives you the "identity"; since in $\mathbf{Z}_4$ this happens for $2$, you may want to shuffle the rows and columns to move that element to be in the third row and column and see what you have then.

Comment: c'est superbe!!

Comment: Apparently not; any reason for the downvote?

Comment: Who downvoted ?

Comment: Don't know; but someone did...

Comment: Since $\mathbb{Z}_n^\times$ is cyclic, reordering can be easily done by picking a generator element (*i. e.*, any other than 1), and computing its power. In this case, the powers of 2 are, in order, 1, 2, 4 and 3, which is the ordering for the first line of the table for $\mathbb{Z}_5^\times$ that will suit the isomorphism.

Comment: @Luke: $\mathbb{Z}_n^{\times}$ is not *always* cyclic. It is cyclic for primes, odd prime powers, $n=4$, and twice odd prime powers; but it's not cyclic for other $n$. For example, $\mathbb{Z}_8^{\times}$ is not cyclic.

Comment: @Luke: Yes, "odd prime power" means "power of an odd prime", not "prime raised to an odd power".  After all, didn't I point out earlier that $n=8=2^3$ doesn't work?

Comment: @Arturo Magidin Ooooh, indeed, so I misinterpreted that expression. Not noticing the connection with *n = 8*, it became ambiguous. Pesky language. (P. S.: comments are piling up. I'll erase my two previous ones.)

Answer (score 5):

Your "naive" definition of isomorphic *almost* coincides with the abstract one. The difference is that apart from renaming you must also be allowed to change the order of the elements. Then you should have no difficulties with $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$ vs. $(\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z})^\times$.

Comment: Note by the way that this little confusion is a good argument for learning the actual definition of group isomorphism, rather than trying to avoid it by only thinking in terms of "group tables".

Answer (score 1):

As a side comment on the two positions expressed in this very old post, maybe worths to recall *why* both of them rightly convey the idea of *isomorphicity*.

---

A group $G$ shows its structure as soon as we allow the internal operation to fully deploy its effects. Accordingly, we can reasonably state the following:

> **Definition 1**. The *structure* of a group $G$ is the set $\theta_G:=\{\theta_a, a\in G\}\subseteq \operatorname{Sym}(G)$, where $\theta_a$ is the bijection on $G$ defined by: $g\mapsto \theta_a(g):=ag$.

Here a problem arises, if we want to determine whether two groups, $G$ and $\tilde G$, "have the same structure", since in general $\operatorname{Sym}(G)\cap\operatorname{Sym}(\tilde G)=\emptyset$, and then any attempt to "compare by overlapping" the structures $\theta_G$ and $\tilde\theta_\tilde G$ is doomed to fail. We can overcome this issue "by transporting" the structure of $G$ in $\operatorname{Sym}(\tilde G)$, and see whether we can made the "transported $\theta_G$" to overlap with $\tilde\theta_{\tilde G}$. If we succeed, then we can rightly say that $G$ and $\tilde G$ are *isomorphic*, since we have been able to bring the *structure* of one *onto precisely* that of the other. So, with reference to the following diagram:

$$
\newcommand{\ra}[1]{\kern-1.5ex\xrightarrow{\ \ #1\ \ }\phantom{}\kern-1.5ex}
\newcommand{\ras}[1]{\kern-1.5ex\xrightarrow{\ \ \smash{#1}\ \ }\phantom{}\kern-1.5ex}
\newcommand{\las}[1]{\kern-1.5ex\xleftarrow{\ \ \ \smash{#1}\ \ }\phantom{}\kern-1.5ex}
\newcommand{\da}[1]{\bigg\downarrow\raise.5ex\rlap{\scriptstyle#1}}
\begin{array}{c}
 &  & \\
G & \ras{\space\space\space f \space\space\space}   &   \tilde G \\
\da{\theta} &  &  \da{\tilde\theta}  \\
\operatorname{Sym}(G) & \ras{\varphi^{(f)}} & \operatorname{Sym}(\tilde G) \\
\end{array}
$$

we set forth this other:

> **Definition 2**. Two groups, $G$ and $\tilde G$, *are isomorphic* if there is a bijection $f\colon G\to \tilde G$ such that the above diagram commutes, namely:
>
> $$\tilde\theta=\varphi^{(f)}\theta f^{-1}\tag 1$$
>
> where $\varphi^{(f)}\colon \operatorname{Sym}(G)\to \operatorname{Sym}(\tilde G)$ is the "structure transporting" bijection defined by $\sigma\mapsto f\sigma f^{-1}$.

Now, as a caracterization of such an "enabling" bijection $f$, the following holds:

> **Claim**. Two groups $G$ and $\tilde G$ are isomorphic (as per Definition 2) if and only if there is a bijection $\psi\colon \tilde G \to G$ such that:
>
> $$\psi(\tilde a\tilde g)=\psi(\tilde a)\psi(\tilde g), \space\space\forall \tilde a,\tilde g\in \tilde G \tag 2$$

*Proof*.

\begin{alignat}{1}
&\tilde\theta=\varphi^{(f)}\theta f^{-1} &\iff \\
&\tilde\theta_\tilde a(\tilde g)=(\varphi^{(f)}\theta f^{-1})(\tilde a)(\tilde g), \space\space\forall \tilde a,\tilde g\in \tilde G &\iff \\
&\tilde a\tilde g=(\varphi^{(f)}\theta f^{-1})(\tilde a)(\tilde g), \space\space\forall \tilde a,\tilde g\in \tilde G &\iff \\
&\tilde a\tilde g=(\varphi^{(f)}(\theta_{f^{-1}(\tilde a)}))(\tilde g), \space\space\forall \tilde a,\tilde g\in \tilde G &\iff \\
&\tilde a\tilde g=(f\theta_{f^{-1}(\tilde a)}f^{-1})(\tilde g), \space\space\forall \tilde a,\tilde g\in \tilde G &\iff \\
&\tilde a\tilde g=f(\theta_{f^{-1}(\tilde a)}(f^{-1}(\tilde g)), \space\space\forall \tilde a,\tilde g\in \tilde G &\iff \\
&\tilde a\tilde g=f(f^{-1}(\tilde a)f^{-1}(\tilde g)), \space\space\forall \tilde a,\tilde g\in \tilde G &\iff \\
&f^{-1}(\tilde a\tilde g)=f^{-1}(\tilde a)f^{-1}(\tilde g), \space\space\forall \tilde a,\tilde g\in \tilde G\\
\tag 3
\end{alignat}

So, $(1)\Rightarrow (2)$, by setting $\psi:=f^{-1}$, and $(2)\Rightarrow (1)$, by setting $f:=\psi^{-1}$. $\space\space\Box$

Therefore, a bijection between two groups with the property $(2)$ is rightly called *isomorphism*.